# How to access records of a model based on a field value of many to many related model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3. There is 2 models.

> **Job** [`id,title,location`]
>
> **Tag** [`id,tag_name`].

The two models have the relation `many to many`.

```
Job belongstomany Tag

Tag belongstomany Job.
```

The pivot table is,

> **job_tag** [`job_id,tag_id`].

How can I get the job records which are associated to a specific tag name.

tags:

```
id.     |     tag_name
--------|--------------------------
1       |          php
--------|--------------------------
2       |          html
--------|--------------------------
```

jobs:

```
id       |    title               |     location
---------|------------------------|--------------------------
1        |   developer            |      Kochi
---------|------------------------|--------------------------
2        |   designer             |      bangalore
---------|------------------------|--------------------------
```

Pivot: job_tag:

```
job_id           |     tag_id
---------------- |-----------------
    1            |       1
-----------------|-----------------
    1            |       2
-----------------|-----------------
    2            |       1
-----------------|-----------------
```

Using a tag name "php", I want to list all jobs which has relation to the  tag name "php".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//$params[tags] contains the data for the search

$jobs = Job::query();
$jobs = Job::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use($params) {
    $query->whereIn('tag_name', $params['tags']);
});
```

The above code worked for me...
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

This might be helpful for you.

Comment: wherePivot in my Job model. it doesnt return data